# using replaceWith on window title depending on browser

Tags: jquery, window, title, replacewith

I have some neat code that displays one `<title>` for a couple seconds after loading, then replaces it with a different `<title>`. The effect we are trying to achieve doesn't work in some versions of Safari or on iPad, so I want to check for Safari--and if the browser is Safari, then cancel the effect. What we have at the moment does not work--I am pretty sure the problem is in the safariFix function but am still a noob and not sure what's wrong:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Uppagus</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uppagusSTYLE.css" />
<link rel= "shortcut icon" media="all" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.uppagus.com/favicon.ico" /> 
<link rel= "icon" media="all" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://uppagus.com/favicon.ico" />
<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="revealTrans(Duration=2.0,Transition=23)">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var isSafari;
  var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
  if(ua.indexOf('safari') != -1) { 
    if(ua.indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
      var isSafari = false;
    } else {
      var isSafari = true;
      safariFix();
    }
  } else {
    isSafari = false;
  }

  function safariFix() {
    $(function() {
      $('#googleFix').replaceWith('<script id="safariFix">function updateTitle() { document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = "Uppagus";</script>');
    });
  }
</script>
<script id="googleFix">
function updateTitle() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'ppagus';
    }, 2000);
}
</script>

...
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script blocks are executed top to bottom as the browser encounters them while parsing the document. So you can't use code in the first script to manipulate any elements *after* that script. You are trying to replace a script element that appears after.

But why try to replace the script at all? Why not just put the logic in the script:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isSafari = ua.indexOf('safari') != -1 && ua.indexOf('chrome') == -1;

function updateTitle() {
    if (isSafari) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = "Uppagus";
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'ppagus';
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

(Note also that your nested if/else structure is more complicated than necessary.)